# numpy: efficient selective multidimensional operations (partial ops)

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way in numpy to do operations ***partially*** along some dimensions? For example, say I have 2 matrices of shapes a=(MxN), b=(NxK) and a 3rd one I want to store the dot-product of a and b into, e.g. c=(MxK). If I just want the dot-product, I can simply do:

```
c = a.dot(b)
```

Now suppose I would like to populate c with the same results, but only *partially* - e.g. only for index 0 along the M dimension. Using a python for loop:

```
for msel in [0]:
    c[msel,:] = a[msel].dot(b)
```

Or maybe for example adding matrix b into matrix a, of sizes MxN but only for indices 0,2 along the N dimension:

```
# Full add would be: a+=b
for nsel in [0,2]:
    a[:,nsel] += b[:,nsel]
```

Sorry if I'm being a little vague here, I currently mainly need such a functionality for the dot and addition operations, but I was thinking to formulate the question in the hope that maybe there's something like this relatively generic that numpy offers of which I don't know.

Update: this seems to work as expected:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,1,2],
              [3,4,5]])
b = np.array([[0,1],
              [3,4],
              [5,6]])
c = np.zeros((2,2))

#c = a.dot(b)
#for d in [0]:
#  c[d,:] = a[d].dot(b)
cond=[True, False]
c[cond,:] = a[cond,:].dot(b) # <--- what I was searching for for dot
print(c)

a=np.ones((2,3))
b=np.ones((2,3))

#a+=b
#for d in [0,2]:
#  a[:,d] += b[:,d]
cond=[True, False, True]
a[:,cond] += b[:,cond] # <--- what I was searching for for add
print(a)
```

I wonder if behind the scenes (C code) numpy really explores only the necessary dimensions and leaves the rest untouched. This would be awesome!

Comment: Think of `b[:,cond]` as generating a  new array object (it may be a `view`).  Then your code does a `dot` with it, or the `b+`.  Then it is assigned to `c[cond,:]`, another indexing operation.  In other words, `numpy` operates in Python, so Python syntax and evaluation order applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a beginner with numpy, the indexing syntax is probably very well known by experienced users. For beginners like me though, I've just confirmed that the above syntax (see update in question) does exactly what I needed, and efficiently. Moreover, there's support for index-selections by both boolean-mask and indexes-lists as well.

Code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

a = np.ones((1000, 2000))
b = np.ones((2000, 1000))
c = np.zeros((1000, 1000))

# Prepare dimensions selection (list)
dims=np.arange(0,500,2)
# Prepare dimensions selection (conditions)
cond=np.full((1000), False)
cond[dims] = True

def full_dot(): c = a.dot(b)
def dot_by_dims(): c[dims,:] = a[dims,:].dot(b)
def dot_by_cond(): c[cond,:] = a[cond,:].dot(b)
def dot_by_pyfor():
    for d in dims:
        c[d,:] = a[d,:].dot(b)

print('Full dot time: {} seconds'.format(timeit.Timer(full_dot).timeit(number=100)))
print('Dot partial python for time: {} seconds'.format(timeit.Timer(dot_by_pyfor).timeit(number=100)))
print('Dot partial by dims time: {} seconds'.format(timeit.Timer(dot_by_dims).timeit(number=100)))
print('Dot partial by cond time: {} seconds'.format(timeit.Timer(dot_by_cond).timeit(number=100)))
```

Output:

```
Full dot time: 4.831596400000002 seconds
Dot partial python for time: 12.7231105 seconds
Dot partial by dims time: 1.4666931999999946 seconds
Dot partial by cond time: 1.5701424000000017 seconds
```

(using a classic python for is about **8.5X slower** than the numpy syntax! Even 2.6X slower than the full-dot, even though it does only partial dotting...)

Comment: Where possible use `numpy` expressions that work with the whole array; avoid Python iterations where possible.  `dot` is quite efficient; though with larger array sizes, memory management complications can favor operating in chunks.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj. I agree it's preferable to do full array ops when possible, in my case I really couldn't afford that, as dictated by the algo I'm working on. Thanks for the tips

Comment: It is perfectly normal to a select a portion of an array to work with. Experiment with different options to see which best in your case.