# numpy: sqrt in place: is this a bug?

Tags: python, numpy, in-place

I'm trying to do sqrt in place on a portion of an array, selected using a boolean mask.

Why doesn't this work:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[4,9],[16,25]], dtype='float64')

np.sqrt(a[[True, False], :], out=a[[True, False], :])
print(a[[True, False], :]) # prints [[4, 9]], sqrt in place failed

print('')

b = np.zeros_like(a[[True, False], :])
np.sqrt(a[[True, False], :], out=b)
print(b) # prints [[2, 3]] sqrt in b succeeded
```

If I'm selecting a single index instead this works (but it doesn't help me since I want to do a sparse update):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[4,9],[16,25]], dtype='float64')

np.sqrt(a[0, :], out=a[0, :])
print(a[0, :]) # prints [2, 3]

print('')

b = np.zeros_like(a[0, :])
np.abs(a[0, :], out=b) # prints [2, 3]
print(b)
```

Comment: Because you are passing `out=a[[True, False], :]` which creates *a new array with a new underlying buffer*, which is discarded because you don't keep a reference to it anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained in the [indexing documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.indexing.html), relevant part:

> Advanced indexing always returns a copy of the data (contrast with basic slicing that returns a view).

Indexing with a boolean array is considered "advanced", hence you always get a copy, and modifying it won't touch the original data. Indeed in your first example `b` is modified but `a` is not. Using indices only returns a "view", and that is why the original data is modified.

Comment: This is so sad. I expected otherwise due to the fact that you can do in place operations to such an indexing expression if it's on the left side, e.g. like a[[True, False],:] += 1.

Comment: @ZuzuCorneliu because item-based setting is distinct from item-based getting. Fundamentally, `a[[True, False],:] ` is *already evaluated* before it is passed to `np.sqrt`

Comment: @ZuzuCorneliu that is different. As mentioned by the other comment, what you wrote is equivalent to `a[[True, False],:] = a[[True, False],:] + 1`, i.e. you create a new array with the result and copy it back into the original array

Comment: @BlackBear Wow. What a revelation. Are you sure that's true? When I'm doing a[[True, False],:] += 1 np allocates a temporary? And here I was happily using something like that all over my code, wondering why the hell it's still slow like crap, even though I've replaced the for's with partial indexing expressions. How do you optimize your code when you need to access partial, sparse data if numpy is keen on doing unnecessary alloc/copy/do-op/copy again/free ops?

Comment: @ZuzuCorneliu you can verify it is true by creating a very big matrix (~30% of your RAM) and observing memory usage double when you do that `+=1`, then go back to the initial level as soon as the operation is finished (that's the copy being garbage-collected). Try to avoid advanced indexing or perhaps you can manage to use actual sparse matrices (from scipy)

Answer (score 0):

The question identifies that an in-place square root is possible on a simple slice.  So given the sparse update, one could loop over the `True` elements of the (sparse) boolean mask doing in-place square-roots on such slices.

It is not as efficient as it hypothetically could be if the boolean mask indexing returned a view of the original array, but it may be better than nothing.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[4,9],[16,25]], dtype='float64')

mask = np.array([True, False])

for (i,) in np.argwhere(mask):
    slice = a[i]
    np.sqrt(slice, out=slice)

print(a)
```

Gives:

```
[[  2.   3.]
 [ 16.  25.]]
```

Comment: Before this question I had this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62500809/numpy-efficient-selective-multidimensional-operations-partial-ops . See the answer there, the for-loop version can be extremely inefficient, even worse than doing data copies apparently. The speed difference is probably explained by the fact that even though numpy does data-copying, the internal operations are very well optimized for contiguous data (and for contiguous data only, which is why they implemented advanced indexing like that, always returning a copy). Sad that they didn't focus on sparse data as well.

Comment: @ZuzuCorneliu Ah okay, that's too bad. When you said "sparse", I was taking it that your boolean mask has a few `True` values and lots of `False` values, so that if you looped over `np.argwhere(mask)` you wouldn't be looping over very many elements. Maybe I misunderstood.

Answer (score -1):

The `sqrt()` does not work in place in general. It returns the modified array. So you have to replace the line `np.sqrt(a[[True, False], :], out=a[[True, False], :])` with `a = np.sqrt(a[[True, False], :], out=a[[True, False], :])` to get the result of the `sqrt` function in array a.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that most numpy operations are not in-place.

Comment: "The sqrt() does not work in place in general" - I don't mean to be rude, but that's a pretty vague statement. Doing np.sqrt(a, out=a) does work, try it.

Comment: This isn't true for somethign with an `out` parameter, i.e. *it modifies `out` in place*